# Не вызывается rest api с nuxtServerInit в Store

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

не работает вызов rest api с nuxtServerInit в Store, попробовал с asyc/await, then, попытался в nuxtServerInit вызвать другой action и там делать commit на mutation но все без полезно то чувство что nuxtServerInit просто не вызывается.

[image: page]

[image: Мой Store]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `nuxt.config.js` пропишите

```
mode: 'universal'
```

или

```
ssr: true
```

подробнее [тут](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store)